# Unable to send the attachment to specified Email Id in ASP.NET,MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is my code in controller.My code works fine by send the subject and body,but I am unable to send the attachment?
Please help me thanks

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class MailController : Controller
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SendMail(MailModel obj,HttpPostedFileBase objFile)
        {
           string from = "vijaycsemvgr@gmail.com";
            MailMessage mailmessage = new MailMessage();

            mailmessage.To.Add(obj.ToMail);
            mailmessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
            mailmessage.Subject = obj.SubjectMail;
            string body = obj.BodyMail;
            mailmessage.Body = body;
            if (objFile != null)
            {
            //    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(objFile.FileName);
            //    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/App_Data/uploads"));
                mailmessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("E:\\6_25_Download\\Resume_Vijay"));
            }
            mailmessage.IsBodyHtml=true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();  //For sending mails,we need an smtp server
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "Vijay@123");// Enter senders User name and password  
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mailmessage);
            ViewBag.Message = "Sent";
          //  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Message has been sent successfully.');", true);
            return View("SendMail", obj);

        }  
        // GET: Mail
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult SendMail()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: I've tried it on my side and it works.Have you stepped through your code?Does objFile have a value and does it go inside the != null block?